# How do I get started with android game development?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adobe

First a little background:
I've done a little coding before in C, C++, Java, and Actionscript 2.0.  I'm most familiar with C programming since I've taken actual classes in it.

I might be interested in learning how to do it with Adobe AIR/Flash CS6, but is it best to start developing in Java and using the Android SDK?  Or can I use C with the SDK?

I'm just a little lost on where to start because whatever route I take there will be multiple things I know nothing about.  I guess I'm just wondering what I should start familiarizing myself with first.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: This question is going to get closed as too general in like 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to do game development, it's still a steep hill to climb, but I would think that a general purpose game engine like [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) would be your best bet. There's still a ton to learn, but it'll all be specific to what you're actually doing, rather than the mountain of stuff you need to learn to get a handle on ActionScript 3 and Flash, and/or native Java Android code.

Ultimately the question you have to ask is "why Android"?  There are a bunch of cross platform development tools (you named one yourself) that will compile to Android.  What's your objective? If it's to write games and sell them, then your best best is not limit yourself to Android and built in an environment that can be easily ported to many places.

Comment: Unity3D only in Windows? Damn, it looked good...

Comment: there's a Mac version (right on their downloads page).

Comment: Only Windows and Mac? Damn it looked good... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with cross platform development tools such as [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) which has been mentioned by [Dr.Dredel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59947/dr-dredel). However, in Native you have so much ability rather than other tools. Its good practice to start with Canvas for 2D game development. To get more experience then dive into pool of OpenGL ES. I started like that. [Apress](http://www.apress.com/) has so many useful books that you can refer to them.

[Pro OpenGL ES for Android](http://www.apress.com/mobile/android/9781430240020),
[Advanced Android 4 Games](http://www.apress.com/mobile/android/9781430240594) (This might be good for you as you said you have experiance in C development),
[Pro Android Apps Performance Optimization](http://www.apress.com/mobile/android/9781430239994),
[Practical Android 4 Games Development](http://www.apress.com/mobile/android/9781430240297),
[Beginning Android 4 Games Development](http://www.apress.com/mobile/android/9781430239871),
[Pro Android Web Game Apps](http://www.apress.com/mobile/android/9781430238195)

Answer (score 0):

Java is the preferred language that should be used for developing Android applications. You may also have to use Eclipse, but there are a few others out there. Personally, when I decided that I wanted to make an Android app, I had no programming language or any knowledge of basic computer science. YouTube videos, source codes, and the development page in developer.android.com help. Knowing Java is very useful. Just practice and study android source codes. You have the background, now you can focus on the product you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop for Android, you'd better off with Java. Forget about C/C++ and native libraries for a while.

1. Get a book. Any recent book will do, just flip through the pages and make sure they don't concentrate on single topic, like "porting a decade old PC game to Android", but instead give a broad explanations, preferably including 2D and 3D development details. Just off the top of my head, "Practical Android 4 Games Development 2011" looked nice when I saw it last time, but I'm sure there are many other decent books.
2. Get the tools. With a decent Linux box it takes about 1 hour to download and install SDK and Eclipse. Android is based on Linux, so while coding on Windows might be fun, I'd recommend against it.
3. Go through the book and SDK examples. Copy/paste the code into Eclipse and make it work. You don't need an actual device for that, emulator would be enough for basic tutorials and examples.
4. After you have finished pp.1-3, you should already have a grasp of Android programming and be ready to participate in some kind of project. Don't start alone, get your friends involved or join an existing development. Working with the skilled people is the easiest way to learn.
5. Have fun! =)

Answer (score 0):

Learning OpenGL *and* the Android SDK at the same time is likely to be a very daunting task. Unless you are already familiar with OpenGL, I suggest the [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) game library. It abstracts OpenGL into what is probably an easier-to-use API for someone beginning with Android game programming.

I would avoid Adobe Air for more ambitious games since it doesn't allow multi-threading.